# Conditionally switch parts of line

Tags: shell, unix, replace, sed

My grepped data has three columns. The first column's position is static while the other two occur in random order. The x and y parts in the scheme below vary. Their lengths are constant. I want to pipe the data and conditionally switch parts of each line so that the three columns are the same for each line.

The lines now:

```
ADDED  IDx  UPDATEDy
ADDED  UPDATEDy  IDx
ADDED  IDx  UPDATEDy
ADDED  UPDATEDy  IDx
ADDED  UPDATEDy  IDx
ADDED  IDx  UPDATEDy
```

What I need:

```
ADDED  IDx  UPDATEDy
ADDED  IDx  UPDATEDy
ADDED  IDx  UPDATEDy
ADDED  IDx  UPDATEDy
ADDED  IDx  UPDATEDy
ADDED  IDx  UPDATEDy
```

I've been trying to write a sed expression that, if the line contains "ADDED UPDATED", switches "UPDATEDy" with "IDx" by copying substrings between different indices, but without luck. I'm not even sure if it's possible without temporarily storing the replaced part in order to be able to replace the last part with it afterwards, so that the parts are switched.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use awk:

```
awk '/ADDED UPDATED/{ t=$3; $3=$2; $2=t } 1' file
```

You could almost certainly get rid of your preceding grep too as awk can do anything useful that grep can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
sed 's/ADDED\( \+UPDATED[^ ]\+\)\( \+ID[^ ]\+\)/ADDED\2\1/' file.txt
```

The regex searches for lines in which UPDATED appears before ID and captures both the UPDATEDx as well as the IDy part. In those cases, the two captured groups are just exchanged (this is what `\2\1` does).
Add the `-i` switch to `sed` to do the substition in-place.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I didn't get this to work. I tried applying it on my different example rows in several ways, but the columns didn't switch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this GNU sed command also,

```
sed -r '/ADDED/s/( +UPDATED\S+)( +ID\S+)/\2\1/' file
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I didn't get this to work with my example columns either.